# tws-api claims to support broadtape news , but all 3 examples give errors

Tags: c++, interactive-brokers, tws

TraderWorkStation (TWS) API gives a api which allows querying of "broad" or general news not tied to a particular stock..

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/news.html

but when I attempt these calls I get an error

My Request Contract

[image]

[image]

```
m_pClient->reqMktData(this->client_id + i, req_contract, news_type, false, false, TagValueListSPtr());
```

Response from callback

```
TestCppClient: ERROR. Id: 255310, Code: 321, Msg: Error validating request.-'b1' : cause - The entered news source is invalid. Valid are: [BRFG, BRFUPDN, DJNL, BZ, DJTOP]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you subscribed to BRF (a paid service)?

A call to

```
m_pClient->reqNewsProviders();
```

will list all providers available to your account via the NewsProviders callback.
See the section 'Checking Subscribed News Sources' in the link you provided.

If you HAVE subscribed, and BRF is not returned as a ProviderCode in the callback I would contact either IBKR support or Briefing.com directly at dbeasley@briefing.com

Otherwise for the free provider, setup the contract as follows (note the 'G's):

```
Contract contract;
con.symbol = "BRFG:BRFG_ALL";
con.secType = "NEWS";
con.exchange = "BRFG";
```

Edit: Ah ha, I see now that all three examples are of paid providers. Probably not the most helpful examples.